# Deleted drivers. How to get them back with LiveUSB?

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg, live-usb

I needed `fglrx` drivers, but for some reason they don't work with my computer. (Login Loops) (AMD Sapphire Radeon R7 User) So I purged them with recovery mode.. but then I was not able to get `xserver-xorg-video-ati` package back due to problems with Recovery Mode and Internet..

I made a LiveUSB, but I don't know how to use it properly to get my dang XOrg package back. I opened Terminal.. now what? How to get access to my Ubuntu with a LiveUSB.. How to make my USB able to fix my Ubuntu with that command:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
```

I just do not remember the commands..

Update: Here's my `fdisk -l`

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048   2254847   2252800   1.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         2254848 781443239 779188392 371.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       781445118 976771071 195325954  93.1G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       781445120 968593407 187148288  89.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       968595456 976771071   8175616   3.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: Have you considered switching to a console with control-alt-f1 and logging in from there OR by pressing ESC at the grub prompt and go to resque mode? That way you use `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati` from command and even reconfigure the display with `dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg` without the need of a Live session.

Comment: Oh yeah. CTRL + ALT + F1 / F2 does not work.. anyways I deleted fglrx by accident.

I need the live season.. this is also the easiest way for me.

Comment: Use the grub method. It is easy too ;-) but you just need to the experience to be comfortable with it.

Comment: Can't I use the LiveUSB method? I am comfortable with stuff like GRUB, but I am just requesting the LiveUSB method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you can mount another installation and trick it into thinking you're using it. It's called `chroot`. Boot to your Live environment and open a terminal. We need to start by finding out what the real installation partition is called. It'll look *like* `/dev/sdb1` but use `sudo fdisk -l` to find out for certain.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
```

You're now root on your real installation. We've cross-mounted the live deives and kernel stuff so everything should Just Work™ Lite®*.

Run whatever it is you want now and then reboot.

<sub>* DKMS —the thing that compiles driver modules dynamically— *might* not compile accurately because you're *running* a different kernel, but it should allow you to get the system into a state where you're just running on open drivers to boot for real and then reinstall whatever you like.</sub>

Comment: SDA1: /dev/sda1  *         2048   2254847   2252800   1.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

SDA2: /dev/sda2         2254848 781443239 779188392 371.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

SDA3: /dev/sda3       781445118 976771071 195325954  93.1G  5 Extended

SDA5:/dev/sda5       781445120 968593407 187148288  89.2G 83 Linux

SDA6: /dev/sda6       968595456 976771071   8175616   3.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

I also saw this: Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Help? I am getting more confused..

Comment: I added that to your question. I believe you want `/dev/sda5` (the big Linux one)

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12212760/ :(

Comment: Fairly big typo on your part there. It's `mnt` not `mvt`. But run that from a new terminal. Or at least run `exit` once to get out of the `chroot` environment.

Comment: One more question: Should it show root@ubuntu:/# if I did all these commands correctly? Or root@(PC name):/#.?

P.S. If it should be root@ubuntu then it worked for me.. 

I am kinda scared :#

Comment: I thought it stayed the same but I honestly can't remember. But on the plus side, if you've done it wrong, you're only "breaking" a live environment (which is restored on reboot anyway).

Comment: Then let me try rebooting on Ubuntu... even though I feel safer on Live environment.. well whatever if it works I will say "Thanks" a lot and will confirm your answer ;D